# "undefined local variable or method `f' " on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app I'm rendering the partial below in the `views/transactions/show.html.erb`, but when I hit `submit` I get this error:

> `undefined local variable or method 'f' for #<PapersController:0x007fa790b51190>`

In this line of the controller:

`f.html { redirect_to "", notice: "Error: Paper Not created!!"}`:

```
<%= form_for ( @newPaper ) do |f| %>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date, class: 'form-text'%>
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </div>
<br />
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :paper_type %>
    <%= f.select(:paper_type, options_for_select(Paper::PAPER_TYPES)) %>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :paper_weight %> :<%= f.number_field :paper_weight, class: 'form-fields'  %> -kg.
  </div>
 <br />
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :env_paper_weight %> :
    <%= f.number_field :env_paper_weight, class: 'form-fields' %>  -kg.
  </div>
  <br />

<br>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Add Paper" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

#### papers_controller.rb

```
class PapersController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_paper, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]
before_action :paper_owner, only: [ :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index 


  all_paper_type_values = Paper.all.pluck(:paper_type).uniq
   @data_for_chart = all_paper_type_values.map do |paper_type|
  { name: paper_type, data: Paper.where(paper_type: paper_type).group_by_month(:created_at).sum(:paper_weight)}
  end

    @pappi = Paper.all

    @newPaper = Paper.new


end

def new
    @paper = Paper.new
end

def create 

    @paper = Paper.new(paper_params)
    @paper.user_id = current_user.id

        if (@newPaper.save)
            redirect_to transaction_path(current_user), :notice => "Post has been saved successfully."
        else
            f.html { redirect_to "", notice: "Error: Paper Not created!!"}
        end 

end




def update
        if @paper.update(paper_params)
        flash[:success] = "Line was successfully updated"
        redirect_to papers_path(@paper)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end     

end

def destroy
    @paper.destroy
    flash[:danger] = "Line was successfully destroyed"
    redirect_to transaction_path(current_user) 
end


private

    def set_paper
        @paper = Paper.find(params[:id])
    end

def paper_params
    params.require(:paper).permit(:user_id, :paper_type, :date, :paper_weight, :env_paper_weight)

end

def paper_owner
            unless @paper.user_id == current_user.id
                flash[:notice] = 'Access denied as you are not owner of this Job'
                redirect_to papers_path
            end
end


end
```

#### transaction_controller.rb

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @paper = current_user.papers.build
    @kwst = current_user.kwsts.build
    @hwater = current_user.hwaters.build
    @transport = current_user.transports.build


end

def show

    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @username = params[:id]

    @newPaper = Paper.new
    @newKwst = Kwst.new
    @newHwater = Hwater.new 
    @newTransport = Transport.new

    @papers = current_user.papers.order(created_at: :desc).limit(5)
    @kwsts = current_user.kwsts.order(created_at: :desc)
    @hwaters = current_user.hwaters.order(created_at: :desc)
    @transports = current_user.transports.order(created_at: :desc)

end    
end
```

I've changed the:

```
<%= form_for ( @newPaper ) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for Paper.new do |f| %>
```

In the `paper_controller.rb` but still get the error.  I'm kind of lost here, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined local variable or method 'f' for
>   <PapersController:0x007fa790b51190>

The error triggers in this line

```
f.html { redirect_to "", notice: "Error: Paper Not created!!"}
```

as you not defined `f` in the controller method.

It seems you are trying write your `create` method using `respond_to`, then the create method should look like below

```
def create 
  @paper = Paper.new(paper_params)
  @paper.user_id = current_user.id
  respond_to do |f|
    if (@paper.save) #not @newPaper
      f.html {redirect_to transaction_path(current_user), :notice => "Post has been saved successfully."}
    else
      f.html { redirect_to "", notice: "Error: Paper Not created!!"}
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you @Pavan, I changed it, now the error is gone but I get this `Error: Paper Not created!!` messages after I hit the submit.

Comment: @DaudiHell Shouldn't `@newPaper` should be `@paper`? Try changing it to `@paper`

Comment: yes, I did that, it works that way but I get `Error: Paper Not created!!` messages after I hit the submit.

Comment: @DaudiHell It failed to save so the else block is triggered. Try `if @paper.save!`, you'd see are there any validation failures that caused the save to fail

Answer (score 0):

The `f` in the two contexts you show is completely unrelated. Views and controllers share attributes (for a given request) but not local variables, and further your `f` variable is limited to the `form_for` block (from the `do` to the matching `end`), it has nothing at all to do with the `PapersController#create` method.

`f.html` could be a respond_to, but thats not really needed if you are **only** supporting HTML.

It is not really clear what you intend `f.html { redirect_to "", notice: "Error: Paper Not created!!"}` since that is in a different controller entirely. If you just want to redirect somewhere, then just use `redirect_to` directly, drop the `f.html` thing.

e.g.

```
redirect_to transaction_path(current_user), notice: "Error: Paper Not created!!"
```

If you want to display errors and keep the original form values then normally, you would have the form (normally an action called `new`) and the `create` in the same controller, and reuse the view.

```
class PapersController
  def new
    @paper = Paper.new
    render
  end
  def create
    @paper = Paper.new(paper_params)
    @paper.user = current_user
    if @paper.save
      redirect_to transaction_path(current_user), notice: "Post has been saved successfully."
    else
      render "new" # form_for will keep values from @paper, can also display @paper.errors
    end
  end
end
```

Allthough it is of course possible to render the same form/view from multiple controllers with full errors, etc. if you wish.